# Why sometimes 'self' isn't available while debugging with lldb?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, llvm, lldb

A lot of time (when it's not every time) I got the following error when I try to print objects on lldb. Is there some build/debug configuration to change or is this an error inside lldb?

```
(lldb) po userLevel
error: warning: Stopped in an Objective-C method, but 'self' isn't available; pretending we are in a generic context
error: use of undeclared identifier 'userLevel'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

I build with llvm and do not strip debug symbols.

Edit: Here is the backtrace:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x001169c5 FanCake-Beta`-[KWUserLevelController addPoints:](, _cmd=0x0029187b, points=15) + 179 at KWUserLevelController.m:53, stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x001169c5 FanCake-Beta`-[KWUserLevelController addPoints:](, _cmd=0x0029187b, points=15) + 179 at KWUserLevelController.m:53
    frame #1: 0x00112172 FanCake-Beta`-[KWEventRealTimeControllergameEngine:hostedGame:didSucceedIn:withScore:](self=0x0b9d7740, _cmd=0x0027a2a7, engine=0x1be5af40, game=0x1be5a850, completionTime=3.59473554800206, score=0) + 421 at KWEventRealTimeController.m:647
    frame #2: 0x0007189a FanCake-Beta`__35-[KMCatchEmGameEngine animateStep6]_block_invoke197(, finished='\x01') + 257 at KMCatchEmGameEngine.m:214
    frame #3: 0x01990df6 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 223
    frame #4: 0x01983d66 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 237
    frame #5: 0x01983f04 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 68
    frame #6: 0x017587d8 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 284
    frame #7: 0x03634014 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
    frame #8: 0x036247d5 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 296
    frame #9: 0x04737af5 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1925
    frame #10: 0x04736f44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #11: 0x04736e1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #12: 0x040367e3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 88
    frame #13: 0x04036668 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #14: 0x01945ffc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
    frame #15: 0x000039a8 FanCake-Beta`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff354) + 94 at main.m:13
    frame #16: 0x00002dc5 FanCake-Beta`start + 53
```

Edit 2: Same thing when I try to print local vars

```
(lldb) po currentUser
error: variable not available
```

If I put some NSLog() in the code, the correct value is printing. But not with the `po` command.

Comment: It might be useful to see the code surrounding the breakpoint, specifically, if you're within a C function, `self` doesn't actually exist.

Comment: @Benoit I only use ObjC and I am in the addPoints: method with nothing funky inside.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I usually get this error when I have compiler optimization turned on. The compiler will generate code which does not necessarily follow your code logic flow.

Go to your project in the navigator -> Target -> Build settings -> Search for optimization level -> expand optimization level -> select the debug line -> change to none in both columns of your project and target.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem. Keep in mind that the app will run slower with no optimization (since it is not optimized) so if you are running computing intensive or AV intensive apps, you will have to switch back and forth to test your app properly.

Answer (score 5):

I was having this problem and it went away when I edited my scheme and set the Run build to Debug.  I had set it to AdHoc for testing Push Notifications and that apparently makes LLDB unhappy.

Answer (score 5):

Because it's optimized away. Let's use an example:

```
void f(int self) {
  // Here, "self" is live:Its value is used in the call to NSLog()
  NSLog(@"I am %d",self);
  // Here, "self" is dead: Its value is never used.
  // I could do self=0 or self=self*self and nobody would know.
  // An optimizing compiler will typically optimize it away.
  // It might still be on the stack (in the parameters passed to NSLog())
  // but the compiler shouldn't assume this.
  NSLog(@"Another function call: %d", 1);
  // If "self" was on the stack, it will probably now have been overwritten.
}
```

Compilers do a lot of things to make your code faster/smaller; forgetting about variables which are no longer needed is a very common optimization.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844719/self-not-available-in-debugger-on-ios-5-1):

In Build Settings, setting Precompile Prefix Header to NO fixed it for me.