# How to access 'self' in Console in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am not able to get dictionary/array value in console while debugging.

It always show message while po dictionary/array like

> error: warning: Stopped in a context claiming to capture an Objective-C object pointer, but 'self' isn't available; pretending we
>   are in a generic context

[Check the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgkY0.png)

Comment: are you using breakpoint

Comment: provide a screenshot

Comment: @TysonVignesh Yes, in both the ways, using breakpoints and using PO command in console.

Comment: may i know where you put the breakpoint is it before the array / initialised or after initialised and assigned with values

Comment: I think you you are try to get the values in a wrong place where the variable is not available or ahead of the scope of the variable.

Comment: @TysonVignesh, I have added couple of breakpoints in the code, inside and outside the blocks, If I am printing the value of any variable using `NSLog()` then its' working fine. The variable is already initialised and contains values which can be logged.

Comment: then put a break point where it prints the value using NSLog() and try to get the value in the console

Comment: I already try all the stuff but this console problem come after installing Xcode 7.3. I think , there is issue related to Xcode 7.3 .

Comment: @Merry I don't think there is any issue, try [self yourArray/Dictionary]

Comment: @Merry Try this thing also, go to build settings of your project ---> build options --->Debug--->Dwarf and Release--->Dwarf with dysm, check this if not like this

Comment: @AkashKR Thanks. It's working but i am little confuse about this thing why it's not directly `po dictionary` ?

Comment: @Merry Every release of Xcode has some kind of issues that are fixed later.

Comment: @Merry plz upvote, other may find it useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the values of properties and variables using `po [self variablename]` in console window. This way you can easily access the variables.

Also you can check with other projects weather the problem is with xcode or in your project configurations.

You can also expand the collapsed value in debug area. if it's expanding then you can access values by simply using `po variablename` otherwise you need to use `po [self variablename]`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd the same issue and found out this solution. Changing this clang module debugging DEBUG to NO and RELEASE to YES will solve your issue.

Checkout this link below.

[Accessing Self in LLDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36571411/4014369)

Answer (score 0):

This is a debugger bug (Yeah, imagine that!)

Simply restart XCode, and it shouldn't be a problem for you anymore :)

EDIT:

Psyche! I was thinking of something else.

You're creating a retain cycle, and as of now, the debugger classifies this specific retain cycle this way (As I said, a bug).

To fix this, create a weak copy of self:

```
__weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
```

Then for the self that's giving you trouble:

Change `self.object` to `weakSelf.object`

Source: ["self" not available in debugger on iOS 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844719/self-not-available-in-debugger-on-ios-5-1)

Comment: I have already tried by restarting the xcode. And I have also seen this error prior to xCode 7.3 in some of the questions in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following screen shot where i have printed the value of an array
[image]

Comment: This thing is not working in my code, that's the problem.

Comment: Can you provide the screen shot like this where you put the break point and how you print the values, that can give us clear context

Comment: I have already attached screenshot in the question it self. Check this [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XgkY0.png) for more details. Even I am not able to expand the Self in the Debug area.