# UIStoryboard how to replace constraints programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uistoryboard, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view controller laid out in a storyboard with autolayout enabled and am looking for a way to change constraints to allow for my view to rotate into landscape and rearrange buttons on the screen. When I try the code below, I get about two dozen "unable to satisfy constraints, breaking constraint..." messages that I cannot really decode.

**Is there a way to dynamically replace constraints from a storyboard with constraints that I specify programmatically?** I want to completely override the layout of the buttons that I defined in a storyboard.

```
-(void)updateViewConstraints
{
    [super updateViewConstraints];

    self.loginButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.getStartedButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.takeTourButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;



    [self.loginButton removeConstraints:self.loginButton.constraints];
    [self.getStartedButton removeConstraints:self.getStartedButton.constraints];
    [self.takeTourButton removeConstraints:self.takeTourButton.constraints];


    one = self.loginButton;
    two = self.getStartedButton;
    three = self.takeTourButton;


    NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"height":@50.0,@"width":@100.0,@"leftSpacing":@110.0};
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(one,two,three);

    [self.view removeConstraints:activeTestLabelConstraints];
    [activeTestLabelConstraints removeAllObjects];

    if(isRotatingToLandscape)
    {

        [self registerConstraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[one(two)]-[two(three)]-[three]-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:metrics views:views];
        [self registerConstraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[one(height)]-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];

    }else
    {

        [self registerConstraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-leftSpacing-[one(width)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
        [self registerConstraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[two(width)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
        [self registerConstraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[three(width)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
        [self registerConstraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[one(height)]-[two(75)]-[three(100)]-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:metrics views:views];
    }


}
```

Updated with Rob's answer, here's the method to remove constraints that I use

```
-(void)removeConstraintForView:(UIView*)viewToModify
{

    UIView* temp = viewToModify;
    [temp removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:temp];

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you want to just remove all the constraints on a view.  Since constraints on a view are often held by an ancestor of the view, it's not obvious how to remove all of the constraints easily.  But it is actually pretty easy.

Removing a view from the view hierarchy removes any constraints betwixt the view and other views outside of it.  So just remove your view from its superview and then add it back:

```
// Remove constraints betwixt someView and non-descendants of someView.
UIView *superview = someView.superview;
[someView removeFromSuperview];
[superview addSubview:someView];
```

If there are any constraints betwixt `someView` and its descendants, those constraints might be held by `someView` itself (but cannot be held by any descendants of `someView`).  If you want to remove those constraints also, you can do so directly:

```
// Remove any remaining constraints betwixt someView and its descendants.
[someView removeConstraints:[someView constraints]];
```

Comment: I noticed that removing the subview from superview does not seem to work for constraints defined for that subview (like pinned height and width )

Comment: The second part of my answer will remove width and height constraints.

Comment: it worked.. but my problem is that if my uiview has buttons in its subviews, the buttons no longer receive touch events when i detach then re-attach their parent.. i donno how to work around that

Comment: ok just so that nobody falls in the same trap as me.. i had to do several things to figure out what was the problem (although some are unrelated to the above problem.. i thought it still could help)
1. couldn't use the life saving [recursiveDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html) on my compiler log.. turned out my compiler optimization setting was [turned on](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15286096/766570)
2. figured out that by setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` on the container view.. and *not* setting a width/height ..>

Comment: <.. layoutcontraint, the container view was always turning out with a 0 width/height.. BAD IDEA! so i simply set up a width/height constraint as well (ie         NSString *visualFormatString1 = @"V:[button(>=41)]-100-|";
        NSString *visualFormatString2 = @"|-[button(>=290)]-|";)

AND DONE!

Comment: Caveat: Any referencing IBOutlets will be nil after removing & re-adding the views.

Comment: Why would they be nil?