# How do I resize my UITableView using Autolayout?

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a UITableView in a ViewController in a Storyboard (not a UITableViewController). What I want to do is add a custom UIView above the TableView in code. When the View is not there, the TableView's top anchor is anchored to PrimaryNavCollectionViewOutlet. I store this constraint as an outlet, and then if I have to add the View, I can use this outlet to remove the storyboard constraint.

I then constrain the inserted View to be below where the TableView was, and constraint the TableView to be below that.

Here's my code:

```
if (_viewAboveTableView != null)
{
     TableView.RemoveConstraint(TableViewTopConstraint);
                
     View.AddSubview(_viewAboveTableView);
     _viewAboveTableView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
     TableView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
     _viewAboveTableView.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;
     _viewAboveTableView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(PrimaryNavCollectionViewOutlet.BottomAnchor).Active = true;
     _viewAboveTableView.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.TrailingAnchor).Active = true;
     _viewAboveTableView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(TableView.TopAnchor).Active = true;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run it, I can't see _viewAboveTableView. I feel like I'm missing something easy, but I can't figure out what. I've tried LayoutIfNeeded() and a few other methods on the View, but they don't make it appear. What have I missed?

Comment: You could post the full code of `add a custom UIView above the TableView in code` . It seems have some constraint conflicts .

Comment: It's pretty much all that I've posted. What are the conflicts you're seeing?

Comment: Where did you add the custom view ? Post the relevant code .

Comment: Line 5 `View.AddSubview(_viewAboveTableView);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem with what I was doing was that `TableView.RemoveConstraint(TableViewTopConstraint);` didn't have the intended effect.

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37964241/812013) I learned that RemoveConstraint is, or is about to be, deprecated in favour of `TableViewTopConstraint.Active = false;`. This made my code work the way that was intended.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add height constraint to _viewAboveTableView.
   Or
2. Make sure _viewAboveTableView has content that will specify intrinsic content size -- it should have properly laid-out subviews with content size (intrinsic or explicit via layouts. e.g. image, label etc.)

My guess is _viewAboveTableView is not getting inflated because it doesn't specify intrinsic content size (height > 0). If it's wrong constraints, you should be able to see it in the console.